# How to restore "collection.anki2" file into ".akpg"?

Tags: backup, anki

I forgot to export an important deck
before formating my D-drive.
Using hard-disk recovery tools,
I got back a “[collection.anki2 file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/whnz5og8y9gs41l/AACvWVv3n07zDN90S2T09eeQa?dl=0)”.

Every time I import it into Anki,
Anki shows a dialog box: 
“.anki2 files are not designed for importing.
If you're trying to restore from a backup,
please see the ['Backups' section of the user manual.][2]”
['corrupt-collections' section of the user manual](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#corrupt-collections)
I couldn’t got a clue, after reading the user manual.

Many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its basically a SQLite 3 file. You can open it with a DB Browser of your choice. Then select the "notes" table, in it are all your cards.

Answer (score 0):

`.apkg` is just a ZIP file. If you zip your `collection.anki2` (which is as mentioned by [HadSmeProblem](https://superuser.com/a/1395932) is a SQLite file) and rename the ZIP file `something.apkg`, you'll be able to import it into Anki.

However, do note that the `apkg` (ZIP) file also contains the media (images, audio, etc.) that the deck references. If your flashcards reference such media but you couldn't recover those from your old disk, the flashcards may look weird, but should still work.

(Having actually lost data like this is the reason I've paid for Dropbox/Boz/similar all these years. Good luck.)